# Send a string instead of byte through socket in Java

Tags: java, port

How can i send a strin using getOutputStream method. It can only send byte as they mentioned. So far I can send a byte. but not a string value.

```
public void sendToPort() throws IOException {

    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket("ip address", 4014);
        socket.getOutputStream().write(2); // have to insert the string
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.print(e);
    } finally {
        socket.close();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: To send a string you must convert it to bytes using some encoding scheme first. UTF-8 is the de-facto standard nowadays.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about using PrintWriter:

```
OutputStream outstream = socket .getOutputStream(); 
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outstream);

String toSend = "String to send";

out.print(toSend );
```

**EDIT**: Found my own answer and saw an improvement was discussed but left out. Here is a better way to write strings using [OutputStreamWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html):

```
    // Use encoding of your choice
    Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));

    // append and flush in logical chunks
    out.append(toSend).append("\n");
    out.append("appending more before flushing").append("\n");
    out.flush();
```

Comment: Note that you are using default encoding here instead of an explicit one, which is dangerous

Comment: PrintWriter is almost always a bad idea IMO. The way that it swallows exceptions is horrible.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah i dont really like my own proposed solution. Lets see if it works for the user. Thinking about a better solution.

Comment: @JunedAhsan: Well just using `OutputStreamWriter` and `write` is as simple, allows you to specify the encoding, and avoids the exception nastiness.

Comment: @Ravindu it will work 'most of the time' depending on what type of content you send over the wire. All strings have to be converted to bytes using a particular encoding. The 'default' encoding can be different in each machine/jvm/os. So you can safely asume you will have problems someday if you don't explicitly set the encoding.

Comment: You can shorten this to `new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream()).print("String to send");` by the way. But it isn't recommended, cause you should`close` the PrintWriter when you're done.

Answer (score 15):

Use [OutputStreamWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) class to achieve what you want

```
public void sendToPort() throws IOException {
    Socket socket = null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw;
    String str = "Hello World";
    try {
        socket = new Socket("ip address", 4014);
        osw =new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        osw.write(str, 0, str.length());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.print(e);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.print(e);
    } finally {
        socket.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Because stackoverflow's horrible 6 character edit amount policy, I have to comment here that the 'UTF-8' should be "UTF-8". Remember, single quotes are for chars, whereas double quotes are use for Strings.

Answer (score 5):

Two options:

- Wrap your `OutputStream` in an [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html), so you can then send the string
- Convert a string to bytes using [`String.getBytes(encoding)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29)

Note that in both cases you should specify the encoding explicitly, e.g. "UTF-8" - that avoids it just using the platform default encoding (which is almost always a bad idea).

This will just send the character data itself though - if you need to send several strings, and the other end needs to know where each one starts and ends, you'll need a more complicated protocol. If it's Java on both ends, you could use [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) and [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html); otherwise you may want to come up with your own protocol (assuming it isn't fixed already).

Comment: eh,.... i'm abit confuse about this socket and its input / output stream. What about the receiving part? I mean how could we differentiate whether the data transferring is just a string / file ? @JonSkeet

Comment: @gumuruh: That sounds like an entirely different question. This question is *just* about sending a string - there's nothing about sending a file. It sounds like you should do some more research, and then ask a new question if you're still confused.

Answer (score 4):

if you have a simple string you can do

```
socket.getOutputStream().write("your string".getBytes("US-ASCII")); // or UTF-8 or any other applicable encoding...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `OutputStreamWriter` like this:

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
out.write("SomeString", 0, "SomeString".length);
```

You may want to specify charset, such as `"UTF-8"` `"UTF-16"`......

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),
        "UTF-8");
out.write("SomeString", 0, "SomeString".length);
```

Or `PrintStream`:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
out.println("SomeString");
```

Or `DataOutputStream`:

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
out.writeBytes("SomeString");
out.writeChars("SomeString");
out.writeUTF("SomeString");
```

Or you can find more `Writer`s and `OutputStream`s in

**The [java.io](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/io/package-summary.html) package**

Answer (score 1):

```
public void sendToPort() throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket("ip address", 4014);
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF("2"); // have to insert the string
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.print(e);
    } finally {
        if(socket != null) {
            socket.close();
        }
        if(dataOutputStream != null) {
            dataOutputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: You will need to use DataInputStream readUTF() method from the receiving side.

NOTE: you have to check for null in the "finally" caluse; otherwise you will run into NullPointerException later on.

Comment: note that the utf encoding is not a standard one, is a modified one.

Answer (score 1):

I see a bunch of very valid solutions in this post. My favorite is using Apache Commons to do the write operation:

[IOUtils.write(CharSequence, OutputStream, Charset)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#write(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

basically doing for instance:
`IOUtils.write("Your String", socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8")`
and catching the appropriate exceptions. If you're trying to build some sort of protocol you can look into the Apache commons-net library for some hints.

You can never go wrong with that. And there are many other useful methods and classes in Apache commons-io that will save you time.

Answer (score 0):

Old posts, but I can see same defect in most of the posts. Before closing the socket, flush the stream. Like in @Josnidhin's answer:

```
public void sendToPort() throws IOException {
    Socket socket = null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw;
    String str = "Hello World";
    try {
        socket = new Socket("ip address", 4014);
        osw =new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), 'UTF-8');
        osw.write(str, 0, str.length());
        osw.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.print(e);
    } finally {
        socket.close();
    }

}
```