# java socket send strings instead of bytes

Tags: java, sockets

I'm new at sending data through sockets but I figured out how to do it now.
My problem is that I can only send and receive bytes, is there a way that I can send and receive strings in stead of bytes? Or is it always bytes?

I'm sorry for my bad understanding of how sockets work but I'm trying (;

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440795/send-a-string-instead-of-byte-through-socket-in-java) question?

Comment: You can just convert strings to bytes and vice versa though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DataStreams and writeUTF. On the other side you can read the Strings with readUTF.

```
        yourSocket = new Socket("yoursocket.ip", port);
        os = new DataOutputStream(yourSocket.getOutputStream());

        os.writeUTF("your string");
```

On the other side you can read it the same way with

```
 is = new DataInputStream(yourSocket.getInputStream());
 String yourString = is.readUTF();
```

Answer (score 0):

To send data over a socket, it must be a `byte[]`.

Using the `<string>.getBytes()` method, you can retrieve a byte representation of the string. The resulting byte array can then be sent over the socket. On the receiving end, use the String constructor `String(<byte array>)` you can re-create the string. Both of these methods allow you to pass a character format as the second parameter (have a look at the JavaDoc). I'd recommend doing this as to make sure that, even on two different platforms, you recieve the same data.